# Is it possible to equal abstract type members in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, abstract

An advantage of generic type parameters over abstract type members seems to be that the former can be equalled, for example:

```
trait A[X]
trait B[Y]
trait C[Z] extends A[Z] with B[Z]
```

Similarly:

```
trait C[Z] {
    self: A[Z] with B[Z] =>
}
```

The assignment of the type parameters says in fact three things: X = Z, Y = Z, and hereby X = Y.

The first case can be represented analogously:

```
trait A { type X }
trait B { type Y }
class C extends A with B { type X = Z; type Y = Z; type Z }
```

However, is something like the second case possible with abstract type members? The following solution won't work since type "Z" cannot be referred to from the self-type definition, which itself must come first:

```
trait C {
  self: A with B { type X = Z; type Y = Z } =>
  type Z
}
```

Strangely, the following seems to compile even if the type requirement of "b" is obviously violated:

```
trait C2 {
    val a: A { type X = Z }
    val b: B { type Y = Z }
    type Z
}

class A2 extends A { type X = Int }
class B2 extends B { type Y = String }
class D extends C2 {
    override val a = new A2
    override val b = new B2
    type Z = Int
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a witness that the type parameters are equal, either `=:=` or `scalaz.Leibniz.===` (which is more general, but means depending on scalaz).

```
class C extends A with B { type Z; val w1: X =:= Z; val w2: Y =:= Z }
```

Then there is no way to instantiate this if the types are not equal, and you can use `w1` and `w2` to "convert" values of type `X` or `Y` to type `Z`.